# Arch: Some very-common PHP packages missing in repo

Tags: arch-linux, php, repository, compatibility

When I establish LAMP environments on Debian, I install some PHP extensions:

```
apt install php-{cli,curl,mbstring,mcrypt,gd}
```

From the above, besides `php-gd`, all packages are missing in Arch.

What are their substitutes, if at all, in Arch? How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275485/how-to-run-drupal-on-arch-linux-if-php-cli-curl-mbstring-mcrypt-are-missing-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every distro splits it up the same way, so some of it is already in the main package.

```
# archlinux with only main php package installed
$ php --modules
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```

Other modules can be found in either standard repository or AUR ( https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/php71-mcrypt/ seems to be one ) and if all else fails - you might have to build it yourself.

That's if you really need a specific extension, and didn't simply install it out of habit. According to Wikipedia, mcrypt is abandonware since 2007.